# Vuejs Datepicker enable a disabled element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker

I have 2 instances of the `<date-picker>`, in which the first captures the start date (`starts_at`) and the second captures the end date (`ends_at`).

As per the design I have in mind, I would like to disable the `ends_at` instance and then re-enable it once the `starts_at` has been applied.

This is my `starts_at` instance:

```
<date-picker v-model="starts_at" @input="enableEndsAt()" valueType="format"></date-picker>
```

This is my `ends_at` instance:

```
<date-picker id="endsAt" v-model="ends_at" disabled @input="checkDate()" valueType="format"></date-picker>
```

This is what I have tried so far. When you change the input, it calls the `enableEndsAt()` function, which looks like this:

```
enableEndsAt(){
  if(this.starts_at === "") {
    return
  }
  var element = document.querySelector('#endsAt')
  element.removeAttribute('disabled')
  console.log(element)
}
```

Comment: Is date-picker our own custom component, or are you using external component libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use disabled as a reactive property:

```
<date-picker id="endsAt" 
     v-model="ends_at" 
     :disabled="disableDatePicker" 
     @input="checkDate()" 
     valueType="format"></date-picker>
```

So, to use this, you could create a property disableDatePicker in your data declaration, and then set it inside your method:

```
data(){ return { disableDatePicker: false }},
...
methods: { ....
enableEndsAt(){
  if(this.starts_at === "") {
    return
  }
  this.disableDatePicker = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm, waiting for 6 minutes so that I can mark is as correct!

Comment: Great. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `<date-picker>` can accept `disabled` property, you can simply bind it to a condition:

```html
<date-picker id="endsAt" v-model="ends_at" :disabled="this.starts_at === ''" @input="checkDate()" valueType="format"></date-picker>
```

so you don't need to put `@input="enableEndsAt()"` on your `starts_at` date picker, and you don't need `enableEndsAt()` function